# Help me a routing server on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, routing

I am developing client/server applications and need to test them on Internet environment. However, I only have one PC without connecting the public internet, so I have a plan to simulate a virtual internet environment on my PC.

I think I will install the virtual machines for my purpose, but I can install only one machine because of my slowly PC.

At the moment, my PC has 2 machines: the host machine (use Windows XP) & the virtual machine (use Windows Server 2003 Ent). Each machine will have 2 network adapter (host-only & internal), and in 2 network adapters, the internal adapter is private on each machine, and host-only adapters are connected together.

With Windows 2003, routing server is ok, but I wonder on Windows XP, are there any routing server product?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Internet Connection Sharing on Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126.

If you're using VMWare as your virtualization solution, it has built-in NAT capabilities for VM networks.

Comment: But it only supports NAT outbound. The virtual machine can connect through NAT adapter but the host machine can't ping to the virtual machine.

I want to simulate a virtual internet environment which 2 computer can ping together.

Comment: Not correct. The host machine has a virtual adapter on the NAT network, so it can ping VMs connected to it.

Comment: Did you try out VMware's built-in NAT? It really is the best solution in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html
So all you need to do is set proper up routing table and add IPEnableRouter to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetServicesTcpipParameters registry and set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said your PC is slow, but you can run a very lightweight VM router using Vyatta community edition. It will run with very minimal amounts of memory & hard disk. Configure the router VM so that one adapter connects to your host machine, and the other adapter connects to your LAN.

This should give you some ideas... http://www.youdontevenrealize.com/blog/2008/06/configuring-home-vyatta-router-with.html